# How do I include other columns in dataframe half hourly to daily resample using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a weather dataframe which is formatted in half hour intervals (simplified below):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'date': ['2019-01-01 09:30:00', '2019-01-01 10:00', '2019-01-02 04:30:00','2019-01-02 05:00:00','2019-01-04 02:00:00'],
                   'temp': [15.2,18.0,4.5,4.5,6.5],
                  'windSpeedMax': [20,90,35,45,15],
                   'windSpeedMax_Dir':['NE','SE','SW','W','S']})
```

My goal is to get the maximum wind AND the direction that wind is coming from each day. Using pandas:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df[~df['windSpeedHigh'].isin(['--'])]
df['windSpeedHigh'] = pd.to_numeric(df['windSpeedHigh'])
df_daily = df.resample('D', on='date').agg({'windSpeedHigh': max})
```

My result is:

```
            windSpeedHigh
date                     
2019-01-01           90.0
2019-01-02           45.0
2019-01-03            NaN
2019-01-04           15.0
```

Which only finds the max wind speed each day

My intended result also needs to include the direction the max wind occurred:

```
            windSpeedHigh    windSpeedHigh
date                     
2019-01-01           90.0    SE
2019-01-02           45.0    W
2019-01-03            NaN    NaN
2019-01-04           15.0    S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `groupby().idxmax()`:

```
idx = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.normalize())['windSpeedHigh'].idxmax()
df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: Using this groupby() the dataset does not sample to daily max wind

Comment: You can chain that with resample.

Comment: The additional columns drop when I use: df_daily = df.resample('D', on='date')[['windSpeedHigh_Dir','windSpeedHigh']].max()